# How to center my width/height transforms?

Tags: html, css, animation

So, I was trying to get an image to, when hovered over, spin 360 degrees and scale up by 1.4, all with its centre staying in place. I tried this:

```
.logo img[data-v-4fbac4e1] {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
content: url(https://i.imgur.com/txz1IXI.png);
transition: width 2.0s, height 2.0s, transform 2.0s;
}
```

with this:

```
.logo img[data-v-4fbac4e1]:hover{
    width: 65px;
    height: 65px;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

and it works fine, but it moves off-centre as it expands. How do I make sure the width and height increase from the centre so it stays in the same place? Sorry if this seems elementary, I'm new to CSS.

Edit: the part of the HTML I'm using looks like this:

```
<a data-v-4fbac4e1 href="/home" class="logo">
    <img data-v-4fbac4e1 src="/img/icons/icon.svg">
</a>
```

If more is required I can add it, but this is the HTML for the image I'm trying to transform.

Comment: Show your HTML, please. CSS is meaningless without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm not entirely sure what you mean, point to which is your culprit and we'll get you sorted out but here's some examples of the differences between techniques.

```css
img, div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1rem;
  height: 10rem;
  width: 10rem;
}

.fancy-img1, .fancy-img3 {
  object-fit: cover;
  outline: red 2px solid;
}

.fancy-img2, .fancy-img4 {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/200) no-repeat center center / cover;
  outline: blue 2px solid;
}

/* grow by height value change transition */
.fancy-img1 {  
  transition: transform .5s, height .5s;
}

.fancy-img2 {
  transition: transform .5s, height .5s;
}

.fancy-img1:hover, .fancy-img2:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  height: 15rem;
}

/* Scale with transition */
.fancy-img3 {  
  transition: transform .5s;
}

.fancy-img3:hover {
  transform: scaleY(1.5) rotate(360deg);
}

/* Scale with keyframes */
@keyframes spinGrow {
  to { transform: scaleY(1.5) rotate(360deg); }
}

.fancy-img4:hover {
  animation: spinGrow .5s forwards;
}
```

```html
<h2>Are you talking about transition height which cause the jumpy effect?</h2>

<img class="fancy-img1" src="https://picsum.photos/200">

<div class="fancy-img2"></div>

<h2>Or actually scale so it remains in its original position?</h2>

<img class="fancy-img3" src="https://picsum.photos/200">

<div class="fancy-img4"></div>
```

Comment: Just tried something along the lines of the second one under 'Scale with transition', it worked perfectly (I tried something similar with my own, except with a comma between 'scale() and 'rotate()' which seemingly messed it up). Thanks very much!